# How to fix the problem with table td width

Tags: html, css

I'm doing my project and I made a table, but some `<td>` elements don't work with the `width` attribute. Please review my code and find the part that's wrong.

```css
table:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 12%
}

table:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 28%
}

table:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 10%
}

table:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(4) {
  width: 25%
}

table:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(5) {
  width: 8%
}

table:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(6) {
  width: 16%
}

table:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(1) {
  width: 24%;
}

table:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(3) td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 6%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="6">
      <p>전형유형</p>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">
      <p class="leftAlignText"><input type="checkbox">일반전형</p>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="6">
      <p>지원자<br/>특기<br/>사항</p>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      <p class="leftAlignText"><input type="checkbox">국가유공자 자녀</p>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="6">
      <p>지역</p>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      <p class="leftAlignText"><input type="checkbox">대전</p>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
      <p class="leftAlignText"><input type="checkbox" />마이스터인재전형</p>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="4">
      <p>특별<br/>전형</p>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">
      <p class="leftAlignText"><input type="checkbox">특례입학 대상자</p>
    </td>
    <td rowspan="3">
      <p class="leftAlignText"><input type="checkbox" />전국</p>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
      <p class="leftAlignText"><input type="checkbox" />사회통합 전형</p>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: `rowspan` is not `colspan`.

Comment: Why would you use both `rowspan` and CSS controlling the width?

Comment: Can you please show an image of your desired table view?

Comment: your first tr has 26 row length and your 2nd tr has 14

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `table-layout: fixed` to table. By default `table-layout` is `auto` which makes the table behave as follows:

- Each cell (`<td>` and `<th>`) width will conform to its content so the widest cell will have the most content.
- Any width not set by content is distributed automatically (this will usually make the columns appear at various widths in an asymmetrically unappealing pattern)

A table that has `table-layout: fixed` allows more control of widths:

- A width set explicitly to a cell (preferably to a `<th>`) will be honored.
- Always assign widths to each column so that they will add up to 100% 0f the tables width else the extra width will be distributed automatically (defeating the purpose of using `table-layout: fixed`).

In general concerning width:

- The total width of cells of a row (`<tr>`) should always be 100% unless there are `colspan` and/or `rowspan` in which case the row in which it has the most number of cells will govern overall width distribution.

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

caption {
  caption-side: bottom;
}

td {
  outline: 1px solid #000
}

.left {
  text-align: left;
}

var {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: tomato
}
```

```html
<table>
  <caption><var>100%</var></caption>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width='12%'></th>
      <th width='22%'></th>
      <th width='6%'></th>
      <th width='12%'></th>
      <th width='22%'></th>
      <th width='12%'></th>
      <th width='14%'></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="6">
        <p>전형유형</p>
        <var>12%</var>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="2" colspan="2">
        <p class="left"><input type="checkbox">일반전형</p>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="6">
        <p>지원자<br/>특기<br/>사항</p>
        <var>12%</var>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <p class="left"><input type="checkbox">국가유공자 자녀</p>
        <var>22%</var>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="6">
        <p>지역</p>
        <var>12%</var>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <p class="left"><input type="checkbox">대전</p>
        <var>14%</var>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">
        <p class="left"><input type="checkbox">마이스터인재전형</p>
        <var>22%</var>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="4">
        <p>특별<br/>전형</p>
        <var>6%</var>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <p class="left"><input type="checkbox">특례입학 대상자</p>
      </td>
      <td rowspan="3">
        <p class="left"><input type="checkbox">전국</p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">
        <p class="left"><input type="checkbox">사회통합 전형</p>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```